# If the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ are $0, 1$, is $A$ is projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

It's easy to prove that a projection has $0$ and/or $1$ as its eigenvalues.

My question is:

> If a matrix has only $0$ and $1$ as its eigenvalues, does that mean that this matrix is a projection? (The zero and identity matrices are of no interest.)

Comment: For a diagonalizable matrix it's true. In general it's false (see answers below).

Comment: Of course, the zero and identity linear transformations are (respectively) projections onto the zero subspace and onto the vector space itself.

Comment: I believe a small change guarantees the matrix is a projection: if all eigenvalues of A are 0 except a single eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, then A is indeed a projection. A is rank-1, so Ax is a multiple of the eigenvector corresponding to the unit eigenvalue $\lambda$, meaning A(Ax) = $\lambda$(Ax) = Ax. Conclude A^2 = A so A is a projection.

Someone please correct me if I am wrong; I am still learning this material myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align} A & = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \end{align}
Then $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda = 0$ with multiplicity $1$ and $\lambda = 1$ with multiplicity $2$.

Note that 
\begin{align} A^2 & = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \neq A\end{align}
means that $A$ is not a projection.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't have 0 as eigenvalue. I intentionally write "and" between 0 and 1

Comment: Oh sorry. I thought you just need one example with all eigenvalues either 0 or 1 as you mentioned the zero matrix and the identity matrix.

Comment: @Mirak It's easy to add a new row and column with a prescribed eigenvalue on the diagonal (and $0$s everywhere else).  As Shalop says above, it's true for diagonalizable matrices, so any counterexample with both $0$ and $1$ as eigenvalues will necessarily be at least $3\times 3$.

Comment: @Mirak Edited. Please read the new answer.

Answer (score 5):

Consider (for any field $\Bbb F$) the linear transformation $\Bbb F^3 \to \Bbb F^3$ defined by the matrix $$A := \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Its eigenvalues are $0, 1$, but it is not a projection because $A^2 \neq A$, which is a consequence here of the nondiagonalizability of $A$. (This example is minimal in the sense that a square matrix with size $< 3$ with spectrum $\{0, 1\}$ is diagonalizable, hence equal to its own square.)

This fails for another reason in the real setting: Regarded as a linear transformation $\Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R^4$, the real eigenvalues of the matrix
$$B := \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ are again $0, 1$, but again, $B^2 \neq B$, so $B$ is not a projection. (Regarded as a linear transformation $\Bbb C^4 \to \Bbb C^4$, this matrix has eigenvalues $0, 1, \pm i$.)

The issues in these two examples (respectively, nondiagonalizability and nonclosure of the base field) are, however, the only obstructions to our conjecture. More precisely, using the Jordan Canonical Form and the characterization that a linear transformation $P$ is a projection iff $P^2 = P$, one can quickly show the following:

> (A linear transformation defined by) a matrix $A$ over an algebraically closed field is a projection iff it is diagonalizable and its only eigenvalues are $0, 1$.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't have 1 as eigenvalue. I intentionally write "and" between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Mirak Ah, I see, the intention wasn't clear to me. I'll modify the examples now.

Comment: As to your 2nd example: it's characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 + 1$, i.e. its eigenvalues are complex! Did I make a mistake in calculations?

Comment: @Mirak Yes, you're correct, but the roots $\pm i$ of the characteristic polynomial are not eigenvalues over $\Bbb R$.